# How to scroll a div left programmatically in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to scroll a div to the location of an element within that div.
The below code works if added to a button but if I try to use it programmatically (dynamically) then it does not work. This is being used in conjunction with Fullcalendar, and should be invoked when viewDidMount is fired. The particular view is the resourceTimelineMonth.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('fc-scroller').item(1).scrollLeft += document.getElementsByClassName('fc-day-today').item(1).offsetLeft
```

[image: What the div looks like]

[image: Where it needs to scroll to (todays date)]

Comment: You could probably achieve the same thing with [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) instead of manipulating the scroll container directly.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('fc-day-today').item(1).scrollIntoView() - I've tried this but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the month view not firing viewDidMount.  Instead of using viewDidMount try replacing it with viewClassNames instead.  It fires on every view change.

Replace:

```
viewDidMount: function(info) {
    // Your code here
}
```

With:

```
viewClassNames: function(info) {
    // Your code here
}
```